# Fill html input box based on data from a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, client-server

I'm using script on google sheets to automate a process.
I have an html with 4 input boxes on the left and 4 input boxes on the right.

When an user input numbers on the input boxes on the right and click in the button "calculate", I add the input data to a spreadsheet and apply a markup to each value. I store them in cells A2:D2 (all this is working)

I want to return these value - with the markup I calculated through regular gsheets formula - to the 4 input boxes in the left.

I don't know how to bring the value that I calculated in the spreadsheet to the input boxes in the left

Function to "getValues"

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();const ws = ss.getSheetByName("GeneratedWSP");var temp = ws.getRange("A2:D2").getValues();
```

HTML for the input boxes (4)

```
    <tr>
  <th scope="row">NL</th>
  <td>Netherlands</td>
  <td> <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">&nbsp€&nbsp</span>
    <input style="width: 120px" type='number' class="form-control" id="price_netherlands"> </td>
     
  <td> </td>
```

In the html I have this script:

```
 function afterButtonClicked(){
document.getElementById("price_netherlands").value = "My value" 
google.script.run.getValues();                    } 
document.getElementById("Calculate_WSP").addEventListener("click", afterButtonClicked);                                                     
</script>
```

I don't know to replace "my value" with the info I returned from the script "getValues".

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please mind that for helping you with your issue it would be easier if you could provide the script you have so far, and maybe a sample spreadsheet and / or images that visualize the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I included part of the code

Comment: Have you read all relevant documentation about `google.script.run`?

Comment: No. I have 0 tech background and it's my first time trying this. I watched a lot of videos and read a lot of articles and was able to learn enough to build this in two weeks. Would appreciate if you could indicate the material where I could learn and research more

Comment: The official documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Answer (score 1):

Html (after button is clicked)

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getValues();
   function onSuccess(temp) {
      temp.forEach(function(r){
    var nee= document.getElementById('price_netherlands');
    nee.value = r[0]});
    }
```

GS

```
function getValues()  
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("GeneratedWSP"); 
var temp = ws.getRange("A2:V2").getValues();
Logger.log(temp);
return temp;
```